# $model->validate() returns true without any attribute assignments?

Tags: yii

I have a model with many attributes, I want to validate before saving it. So at some I would have only model initialization but no attribute assignments

```
$model=new patient();   $model->validate();
```

yet it returns true, I have many attributes set to required. I don't understand how does this happen?

Is there a way to validate a model before saving it even though no attributes are assigned to the model?

Comment: just echo or print your model or model attributes and check any default values are assigned.

Comment: Oops! A mistake yet a good learning. I missed scenario while initializing.

Comment: Thanks Saravankg. I tried that well eventhough none of them initialized it still returned true. Now I included the scenario now it's fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your have validation rules but You may Miss the scenario's on validate .

Check the validators on your current object model by this

```
print_r($model->validatorList);
```

refer this [link](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CModel#validatorList-detail)

Answer (score 0):

You can validate a model at any time once it is created.

Let's look at the sequence of events :-

You have created a model class :

```
class User extends CActiveRecord
{
  ... 
}
```

This creates a template for the patient class, which inherits from CActiveRecord, which means it has inherited functions available to it. So, while your class files does not the activate() function, it inherits it from the CActiveRecord class.

Now you create an instance of the class

```
$patient1 = new patient;
```

This means there is now some space in memory that exists for patient1. It has values. Some may be empty and some not (for example, they may have a default value).

So, at any time, you could

```
$model->validate();
```

This would change the model to include the error messages. To get the errors that have been raise, use

```
$allErrors = $model->getErrors()
print_r($all_errors); // This will show you the structure.
```

To print the errors in a neat way, use

```
echo CHtml::errorSummary($model);
```